# how to set a div width inside a fluid container element?

Tags: html, css

I have a container element:

```
div#container {
  width:100%;
  height: 20px;
  overflow:hidden"
}
```

Inside this container, I have three child divs that are floated `left`.
First and third child divs have `width = 100px`

How do I style the second div so that it takes the remaining space ?

nb: `css` only, no `javascript`.

Comment: Can you do float:right to third one ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can change to `float:right` the third div, I recommend you the following layout:

```
div#container { width:100%; height: 20px; overflow:hidden;display:table; }
div#div1 { float:left; width:100px; display:table-cell; }
div#div2 { margin-left:100px; margin-right:100px; width:100%; display:table-cell; }
div#div3 { float:right; width:100px; display:table-cell; }
```